# How to set a break point on other people's website on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

There is a JS code snippet
`var FINISH_TIME = 20;`
on a website.

It means a user has to wait FINISH_TIME seconds to do the next step. I can modify it via the Console panel `FINISH_TIME = 1`, but it can work only if I rapidly input it and hit the Enter key.

Someone told me (actually showed me), he could set a break point after `var FINISH_TIME = 20;` and hit F5 to refrest the website to let the code runs onto the break point. We can safely execute `FINISH_TIME = 1` when the code onto the break point.

But I foget how to set such a break point.

Comment: im not sure what do you need, but you can use localstorage and sessionstorage for create something like memory. What do you mean break point? Please create minimal example

Answer (score 1):

I find the way. In the Sources Panel, find the current website js, find the line, Ctrl+B

[image]